# How to edit a value inside of a dictionary inside of array in MongoDB?

Tags: python, arrays, database, mongodb, pymongo

```
{
    "_id": 1359185710985371235,
    "main": 2,
    "streamers": [{"name": "me", "count": 1},{"anothername", "count": 0}]
}
```

hey, I have a problem with mongodb and pymongo so basically i want to edit `"count"` inside of `"streamers"` . like i want to change count of `"name": "me", "count": 1` to  `"name": "me", "count": 3`How can i do it?
Please answer if you know MongoDB and also provide a console command on how to do it.

Comment: How is the document to update found inside array? By name? And do you want to update one only doc inside array, or can there be multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `mongo` shell:

```
db.example.insertOne(
{
    "_id": NumberLong("1359185710985371235"),
    "main": 2,
    "streamers": [ { "name": "me", "count": 1 },{ name: "anothername", "count": 0 } ]
} )

db.example.updateOne( 
  { _id: NumberLong("1359185710985371235"), 'streamers.name': 'me' },
  { $set: { 'streamers.$[st].count' : 3 } }, 
  { arrayFilters: [ { 'st.name': 'me'  } ] } 
)
```

From Python shell using PyMongo:

```
db.example.update_one( 
  { '_id': 1359185710985371235, 'streamers.name': 'me' }, 
  { '$set': { 'streamers.$[st].count' : 3 } }, 
  array_filters = [ { 'st.name': 'me'  } ] 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pymongo way to do it:

```
import pymongo

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']
# Data setup
db.mycollection.insert_one({"main": 2, "streamers": [{"name": "me", "count": 1},{"name": "anothername", "count": 0}]})

record = db.mycollection.find_one({"main": 2})
streamers = record.get('streamers')

for index, streamer in enumerate(streamers):
    name = streamer.get('name')

    if name == "me":
        streamer['count'] = 3
        streamers[index] = streamer

record = db.mycollection.update_one({"_id": record['_id']}, {'$set': {'streamers': streamers}})

print(db.mycollection.find_one({"main": 2}))
```

Output:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5e904277152eaccd43dddf8d'), 'main': 2, 'streamers': [{'name': 'me', 'count': 3}, {'name': 'anothername', 'count': 0}]}
```